# PendingIntent AlarmManager does not fire when the screen goes into sleep mode

Tags: android, android-broadcast

Need to update the content in my view every x seconds these X seconds depend on the duration of a schedule that varies. 
I'm using `AlarmManager` to schedule this upcoming action and firing a `Broadcast` and then run the routine of updating my view again, the problem that when the device enters 
in sleep mode, the pendent action is not called.

**Edit:**

I have a `ViewPager`, and each must update a `Fragment` (`List <Object> mList`) 
every x seconds these x seconds depend on the duration of a schedule that varies, and each `Fragment` also has its own time to update this list.

To this end, each `Fragment` I have an instance of my class `MyReceiverUpdate`, and dynamically record the receiver because the `Fragment` are independent, and the event can not affect the other.

I'm using `AlarmManager` to schedule future action with this (`PendingIntent` `Broadcast`), this broacast then perform a routine to update my list of objects, the problem that when the device enters 
in sleep mode, the action is not performed.

//method to register my pending action

```
public void updateView(long millis){

    final Intent intent = new Intent( ACTION_NAME_UPDATE_VIEW);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( GuideBaseFragment.this.getActivity(), mId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );

    final AlarmManager alarmManager = ( AlarmManager ) getActivity().getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE );
    alarmManager.set( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, millis, pendingIntentCleanViewNow );
}
```

**My Broadcast**

```
public class MyReceiverUpdate extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive( final Context context, final Intent intent ) {

        //need update view

        //Edit
        new UpdateListAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor( AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, ( Void ) null );
    }
}
```

anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: "the pendent action is not called" -- how have you determined this? What **exactly** is `// need update view` doing? Why are you using `AlarmManager` with a dynamically-registered receiver?

Comment: @CommonsWare,I edited the question, putting more information!

Comment: "I have a ViewPager, and each must update a Fragment (List <Object> mList) every x seconds these x seconds depend on the duration of a schedule that varies, and each Fragment also has its own time to update this list" -- use `postDelayed()`. Or, at worst, use `ScheduledExecutorService`. Using `AlarmManager` for this scenario is "swatting a fly with a Buick" (i.e., inappropriate).

Comment: @CommonsWare, Yes, it's a way of doing, I would have to persist the x seconds in a `SharedPreferences`, or using `onSaveInstanceState()` even when the `ViewPager` recreate the `Fragment` again record the `postDelayed()` with these seconds if still need, but ultimately ended up finding a way to solve the problem using `AlarmManager` it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to leave the matter open, with just solving my problem, and also to leave here was recorded as solved.

For the feature I was implementing it was acceptable to keep the the screen on while this was kept open course, so I followed the doc's Android.

[Keeping the Device Awake](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#screen)

It was something like the code below, my broadcast is dynamic and inner of my Activity

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {

    public class MyReceiverUpdateSchedules extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

        private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

        public void acquire( final Context ctx ) {

            if ( this.wakeLock != null ) {
                this.wakeLock.release();
            }

            final PowerManager pm = ( PowerManager ) ctx.getSystemService( Context.POWER_SERVICE );
            this.wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock( PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "aqs_wake_lock" );
            this.wakeLock.acquire();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive( final Context context, final Intent intent ) {
            this.acquire( context );

            // code going here
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( final Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    }
}
```